# How can I edit the Users Privileges with Local Security Policy in Windows Server 2016?

Tags: windows, security, privileges, ms-security-essentials, security-policy

I am creating a pentest scenario and I want that a user has the `SeImpersonatePrivilege`.
So, I install the **Windows Server 2016** in a virtual machine. Then, I created the Administrator user and a common user.

Answer, [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27901893/using-powershell-seimpersonateprivilege-granting-to-managed-service-account/27921711#27921711), show how to do it: **Open the Local Security Policy** and edit in *Local Polices* -> *User Rights Assignment*.

Another options was use the program **ntrights**, [like this tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/88118-change-user-rights-assignment-security-policy-settings-windows-10-a.html).

But, no matter what I change, I always get this answer in **cmd.exe**:

```
C:\Users\test_user>whoami /priv

PRIVILEGES INFORMATION
----------------------

Privilege Name                 Description                      State
=============================  ==============================   =========
SeShutdownPrivilege            Shut down the system             Disabled
SeChangeNotifyPrivilege        Bypass traverse checking         Enabled
SeIncreaseWorkingSetPrivilege  Increase a process working set   Disabled
```

How can I edit the user privileges?

Comment: Can you just indicate what you did in the question instead of linking to an external website?

Comment: Lol, I did what the tutorials I linked say to do :) The windows show no error, but it didn't update the privileges of the user.